# ssh to remote server from Gitlab CI: ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory. Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ssh-keys

I use GitLab for CI/CD and I would like to ssh to my Raspberry Pi for deployment.
I generated a new `ED25519 SSH` key pair, added the private key to variables and the pubic key to deploy keys.

My `gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like this:

```
deyployment:
    stage: deploy
    image: ubuntu:latest
    before_script:
      - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
      - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
      - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > key
      - chmod 600 key
      - ssh-add key
      - rm key
      - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
      - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
      - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    script:
      - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no pi@IP_ADDRESS 'cd dockerproject2 && mkdir test'
    tags:
      - ssh
```

I get this output after running the deployment job:

```
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no pi@IP_ADDRESS 'cd dockerproject2 && mkdir test'
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied, please try again.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/X11R6/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
pi@IP_ADDRESS: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

For now I just use the ssh key. I'm not sure, but the output `Permission denied (publickey,password)` looks like the Raspberry Pi also needs the password.

I also tried to use the `id_rsa` key in the `~/.ssh` folder. I generated the folder `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and saved a copy of the `id_rsa.pub` file there. This gave me the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Wow this was kind of stupid. I got this error because I tried to run the deployment with a shell runner. But it needs to run with a docker runner. At least in my case.